# validateForm for data in loop

Tags: javascript, php, forms, submit

I'm new here and my english is not perfect.

I want to validateForm that examined the forms are not empty or if the data are numbers.
If not, then the message and I would like to previous data in forms have.
If so, then the message and redirect to another page.

Forms are created in the loop: for.
I can not find a solution, I tried in javascript, but maybe you know other solutions. Thank you.

```
<form name="ilosc" method="post" action="test5.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="#">
<?php

            for($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++) 
                {
                echo '<tr><td><input type="text" size=7 name="xxx['.$i.'][ilosc]"/></td></tr>'; 
                }
            echo    '<p><input type="button" value="...Add..." onclick="validateForm()"/></p></form>';

         ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["ilosc"]["xxx['.$i.'][ilosc]"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="") {
          alert("Stop");
        }
        else
            document.form.submit();
        }
        </script>`
```

Comment: Ok, I read it wrong. You aren't defining validateForm  in the PHP loop. Fine, but you still need to use a Javascript loop in validateForm. As it stands, you are only validating the last index.

Comment: Also, validate functions just return true or false for the validation.  Don't call `document.form.submit();` in the validate function. That will just make like an infinite loop I think, since `onsubmit' calls the validate function. If you return true in the validate function it will submit already, and if you return false it will not.

Comment: The value of form controls are strings, so `x==null` will always return false, even where *x* is an empty string.